# How to resize the Android partition on an SD card for the Asus Tinker Board or other SBC

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, partitions

So, I have an Asus Tinker Board, and as of today, I have a stable running build of Android with Google Play that runs nicely, except for one thing. The img file I used does not expand out when writing it to my SD card, and thus I'm left with a paltry 5.69GB total from my 32GB SD Card.

My question is this: How can I expand the storage on the SD card?

Windows cannot recognize my SD card partitions for android at all, and apps like AParted from Google Play just seem to crash my TinkerBoard. Any suggestions? Or should I just live with the joys of a lovingly stable build, and add a USB thumb Drive for additional storage? (Admittedly, I'm only using 1.4GB of the 5.69GB after installing my crap so, it's livable, but still a bit disappointing.)

Answer (score 1):

The tinker board SD card size issue when installing Miker´s Android with PlayStore pre installed: One has to perform a factory reset from the Android Settings /Backup&Reset. Wait 5 min to reboot and once it´s ready update Google Play Services.

For more details see this thread: 
https://tinkerboarding.co.uk/forum/thread-1204-page-2.html